# How can I work around Windows File Protection such that I can rename a system file?

Tags: windows-registry, rename

How do I use *PendingFileRenameOperations* to rename a file which is in use?  Especially system files, like `tcpip.sys`.  I have created a key `PendingFileRenameOperations` (REG_MULTI_SZ) in

```
HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager
```

And wrote there something like this:

```
\??\C:\windows\system32\tcpip.sys \??\C:\windows\system32\tcpip.bkp
```

I have found that Windows File Protection doesn't let me do that. What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you have an error in the [long filename prefix syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#maxpath).  Instead of `\??\`, try `\\?\`.

Comment: I know it,but try to rename system file, like tcpip.sys .It's not working on system files :(

Comment: I found that Windows File Protection (**WFP**) doesn't let me do that. But I don't know how to disable it.Help please.